# How to call transfer function using Contract Address

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereumjs

I approve the contract address for the tokens of some wallet address to send the tokens. Now, how can i call the transfer function using contract address.
Thanks in advance.

```
function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) public virtual override {
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(to != owner, "ERC721: approval to current owner");

        require(
            _msgSender() == owner || isApprovedForAll(owner, _msgSender()),
            "ERC721: approve caller is not owner nor approved for all"
        );
        allowed[msg.sender][to] = tokenId;

        _approve(to, tokenId);
    }



 function _transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount
    )   public  returns  (bool ) {
         // balances[_from] -= _amount;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _amount;
          _transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
            return true;
    }
```

how can i call the transfer function using contract address?

Comment: Do you want to call the transfer function from another contract?

Comment: no i want to call it in within this contract

Comment: I honestly don't know what your question is

Comment: Hi i explain one second

Comment: Actually i want to make a contract in which i have one master wallet which has many Nfts. So i want the contract address to send the tokens on the master wallet behalf

Comment: so i approve the contract address but i donot know after approving it how i can call the transferFrom using contract address

Answer (score 0):

Your contract that owns the NFTs must have the code to interact with the NFT contract. The NFT contract is where the records of who is the owner of which ID are, also in that contract must be the functions to approve and transfer.

So as a pseudocode it would be something like this.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

//ERC721 interface
//documentation 
//https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721
import "./IER721.sol";

contract OwnerNFT{
    IERC721 public NFT;

    function tranferNFT(
             uint256 idNFT,
             address _to
    )public returns(bool){
      ...    
      NFT.Transfer(address(this),_to, idNFT);    
     ...
    }

    //send address smartcontract NFT 
    constructor(address NFT) {
          NFT = IERC721 (NFT);
     }
}
```

Comment: HI jeissoni Thanks for the answer actually i have only one contract in which i have all the functions related approve etc. but i want to know how can i call transferFrom function using contract address instead of my wallet address such as msg.sender

Comment: I give up hahahahaha I don't understand what you need

Comment: hilarious! hehehe ok i will try to resolve then i will come back but Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is confusing, where is this function? are you interacting with ERC20 token contract or you trying to call functions of contract in your contract using interface?

If you trying to call Using interface in your contract, at first you need to define ERC20 token using token address in your contract this way:

```
IERC20 public token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
```

Then call approve an transfer function in your contract like that:

```
function _approve (address _spender, uint256 _amount)public {
   token.approve(_spender, _amount);

function _transferFrom (address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount)public{
   token.transferFrom (_from, _to, _amount);
```

Note that to calling these functions, at first you need to import ERC20 Interface (IERC20) above your contract.